# Toggle visibility property of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, toggle, show-hide

I have an HTML 5 video in a div. I then have a custom play button - that works fine.
And I have the video's visibility set to hidden on load and visible when the play button is clicked, how do I return it to hidden when the play button is clicked again?

```js
function showVid() {
  document.getElementById('video-over').style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

```css
#video-over {
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7)
}
```

```html
<div id="video-over">
  <video class="home-banner" id="video" controls="">
    <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
    <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.webm" type='video/webm' />
    <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.ogv" type='video/ogg' />
    </video>
</div>

<button type="button" id="play-pause" onclick="showVid();">
      <img class="img-home-apply" src="/wp-content/images/apply-pic.png" alt="Apply Now">
      </button>
```

I'm basically just trying to toggle it between the two states of visible and hidden except I can't use toggle because that show's and hides the div. I need it there, just hidden, so it maintains the correct height.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Using jQuery:

```
$('#play-pause').click(function(){
  if ( $('#video-over').css('visibility') == 'hidden' )
    $('#video-over').css('visibility','visible');
  else
    $('#video-over').css('visibility','hidden');
});
```

Comment: thank you... I just wasted a half hour of my life. my head just automatically went to "onclick" because I was working with a button. I really appreciate it! @tb11

Comment: You can use `onclick`. You just need to put the toggling logic inside the `showVid()` function. Well, then it would be a `toggleVid()` function.

Comment: $('#video-over').css('visibility', $('#video-over').css('visibility') == 'hidden' ? 'visible' : 'hidden');

Comment: Just for future reference Visibility and Display work differently. Display applies hierarchically to inner divs, while visibility in some cases does not. Here is the same for display: `$('#ivideo-over').css('display', $('#ivideo-over').css('display') == 'none' ? 'block' : 'none');`

Comment: Great answer but I also recommend the use of the display property with none/block as the options. visibilities will 'reserve' the space for the div, depending on your UI that will likely not look all that great. The display property treats it as if it doesn't exist so your UI isn't effected until... it does..

Answer (score 37):

According to the jQuery docs, calling `toggle()` without parameters will toggle visibility.

```
$('#play-pause').click(function(){
   $('#video-over').toggle();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Q47ya/

Comment: note the difference between the css properties 'visibility' and 'display'. 'toggle()' changes the 'display' property which will hide the element and makes the space "available" for other elements whereas with 'visibility' the element keeps occupying space. as the OP states in the last sentence, that's why 'toggle()' won't work here

Comment: "According to the jquery docs calling toggle() without parameters will toggle visibility." No It doesn't. visibility and display are two different things and toggle works on display, not visibility.

Comment: if you want to manipulate server side content `display :none ` is not an option toggle() will not work

Answer (score 2):

There is another way of doing this with just JavaScript. All you have to do is toggle the visibility based on the current state of the DIV's visibility in CSS.

Example:

```
function toggleVideo() {
     var e = document.getElementById('video-over');

     if(e.style.visibility == 'visible') {
          e.style.visibility = 'hidden';
     } else if(e.style.visibility == 'hidden') {
          e.style.visibility = 'visible';
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To clean this up a little bit and maintain a single line of code (like you would with a `toggle()`), you can use a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) so your code winds up looking like this (also using jQuery):

```
$('#video-over').css('visibility', $('#video-over').css('visibility') == 'hidden' ? 'visible' : 'hidden');
```

Answer (score 0):

To do it with an effect like with $.fadeIn() and $.fadeOut() you can use transitions

```
.visible {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s linear;
}
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s 1s, opacity 1s linear;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better if you check visibility like this:
`if($('#video-over').is(':visible'))`

Answer (score 0):

```
$.fn.toggleVisibility = function (state) {
    return this.each(function () {
        $(this).css("visibility", state ? "visible" :
            (state === false ? "hidden" :
                $(this).css("visibility") === "hidden" ? "visible" : "hidden"));
    });
};
```

Then

```
$('#video-over').toggleVisibility();
```

or

```
$('#video-over').toggleVisibility(true);
```

or

```
$('#video-over').toggleVisibility(false);
```