# How to show hide div with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this markup that is dynamically generated. However when there is two divs generated i want a button that will toggle between the two. here is my code.

```
<div class="threeSixtyContainer">

     <div class="toggle"><embed height="350" flashvars="site=lexmoto" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" src="models/ZS125-50/360/ZS125-50_Blue.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="500"></div>
     <div class="toggle"><embed height="350" flashvars="site=lexmoto" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" src="models/ZS125-50/360/ZS125-50_Black.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="500"></div>

</div>
```

How could i add a toggle button which would toggle between the two divs. so one is hidden press the button and it gets changed to display block and the other gets display hidden.

Comment: possible duplicate of [toggle visibility of div jquery javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050761/toggle-visibility-of-div-jquery-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

when you have a button with id `#button` , you can use following code:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    $('.toggle').toggle();
});
```

if you make sure one is visible, and one is hidden as initial state. this will work perfectly

Answer (score 1):

I prefer hide all & after show current. It's friendly to addition of future elements and is a simple/straightforward way to say "leave only this button visible!".

CSS:

```
.toggle {
    display: none;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.toggle').first().show();

    $([button]).click(function(){
        $('.toggle').hide();
        $(this).show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.toggle:first-child').hide();
  $('#toggle-button').click(function() {
    $('.toggle').toggle();
  });
});
```

Provided your button has `toggle-button` as an `id`.

Answer (score 1):

Kinda shooting from the hip here.

```
<div class="threeSixtyContainer">
     <div class="toggle"><embed height="350" flashvars="site=lexmoto" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" src="models/ZS125-50/360/ZS125-50_Blue.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="500"></div>
     <div class="toggle"><embed height="350" flashvars="site=lexmoto" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" src="models/ZS125-50/360/ZS125-50_Black.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="500"></div>
     <a href="javascript:;" id="button">Toggle</a>
</div>
```

And your JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button').on('click',function(){
        objToggle = $('.toggle');
        if(objToggle.eq(0).is(':visible')){
            objToggle.eq(0).hide();
            objToggle.eq(1).show();
        } else {
            objToggle.eq(1).hide();
            objToggle.eq(0).show();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="threeSixtyContainer">

 <div class="toggle"><embed height="350" flashvars="site=lexmoto" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" src="models/ZS125-50/360/ZS125-50_Blue.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="500"></div>
 <div style="display:none;" class="toggle"><embed height="350" flashvars="site=lexmoto" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" src="models/ZS125-50/360/ZS125-50_Black.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="500"></div>
```

javascript:

```
$('#togglebutton').click(function(){
    $('.toggle').toggle();
});
```