# div changing its place how to prevent that

Tags: jquery, button, toggle

my question is when 'vartalo' div is clicked away with 'a' button then 'pää' div changes its position and comes to 'vartalo' divs place, how to prevent that, mean i want when i toggle'vartalo' div it will not affect other divs position. sorry my english

```js
$(function() {

  $('.nappulat').on('click', function(p) {

    p.preventDefault();

    var panelid = $(this).attr('data-panelid');

    $('#' + panelid).toggle(1).html('hello')

  });

});
```

```css
#memberlist_links a {
  left: 800px;
  font-size: 70px;
  position: relative;
  left: 800px;
  padding: 0px;
  color: red;
  margin: 0px;
}
.paneelinpaa {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 70px;
}
.paneelinvartalo {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: lightblue;
  font-size: 70px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="all">

  <div class="backgroound">

    <div id="panel1" class="paneelinvartalo">vartalo

    </div>

    <div id="panel2" class="paneelinpaa">pää

    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="memberlist_links">

    <br>

    <a href="#" rel="" class="nappulat" data-panelid="panel1">A

        </a>

    <br>
    <a href="#" rel="" class="nappulat" data-panelid="panel2">B

              </a>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use toggle since it effects `display` css. You need to change visibility.

```js
$(function() {

  $('.nappulat').on('click', function(p) {

    p.preventDefault();

    var panelid = $(this).attr('data-panelid');

    $('#' + panelid).toggleClass('hidden visible'); //toggle visibility
    $('#' + panelid).html('hello');

  });

});
```

```css
.hidden{
  visibility:hidden;  //hide the visibility
}
.visible{
  visibility:visible;  //show the visibility
}
#memberlist_links a {
  left: 800px;
  font-size: 70px;
  position: relative;
  left: 800px;
  padding: 0px;
  color: red;
  margin: 0px;
}
.paneelinpaa {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 70px;
}
.paneelinvartalo {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: lightblue;
  font-size: 70px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="all">

  <div class="backgroound">
    <!--Also add visible class to toggle that-->
    <div id="panel1" class="paneelinvartalo visible">vartalo

    </div>
    <!--Also add visible class to toggle that-->
    <div id="panel2" class="paneelinpaa visible">pää

    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="memberlist_links">

    <br>

    <a href="#" rel="" class="nappulat" data-panelid="panel1">A

        </a>

    <br>
    <a href="#" rel="" class="nappulat" data-panelid="panel2">B

              </a>

  </div>

</div>
```

Or you can just use this. (first answer)
[toggle visibility of div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050761/toggle-visibility-of-div)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the visibility to hidden or visible instead. That way the element hold its size and content but you don't see it anymore.

```
$(function() {
    $('.nappulat').on('click', function(p) {
        p.preventDefault();
        var panelid = $(this).attr('data-panelid');
        var cssVisilibty = $('#' + panelid).css('visibility') == 'hidden' ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
        $('#' + panelid).css('visibility', cssVisilibty).html('hello');
    });
});
```

[See it in action](https://jsfiddle.net/L9h21t2p/)

NOTE: The content of the clicked div will be changed because of the `.html('hello')`

Also you can do a little optimisation by replacing `$('#' + panelid)` by `$panel` and replace the line

`var panelid = $(this).attr('data-panelid');`

by

`var $panel = $('#' + $(this).attr('data-panelid'))`

Comment: thnak you for responding