# How to display full sized image when thumbnail is clicked?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, thumbnails

I have a list of vehicles, and each vehicle has its own image. Right now the thumbnail is displaying of the image is displaying, I would like to display the full size image when the thumbnail is clicked. It gets the image name from a database (c.VehicleImage). How can I create an onClick event for imgVehicleImage?

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="3">
        <asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgVehicleImage" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Code behind:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.VehicleImage))
{
    imgVehicleImage.Visible = true;
    imgVehicleImage.ImageUrl = "/thumbnail.ashx?ImgFilePath=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["VehicleImageFolder"] + Company.Current.CompCode + "\\" + c.VehicleImage + @"&width=200&height=200"; ;
}
```

Comment: You bind a click event of thumbnail and replace the image source dynamically or you can add two divs. its upto you.

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML use an `asp:Image` for both the thumbnail and image, but have the image hidden.  Then when the thumbnail is clicked, hide the thumbnail and show the image.

You can use JQuery.  See [toggle visibility of div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050761/toggle-visibility-of-div) for an example.