# How do I set a function to a certain class

Tags: jquery

I am trying to display a div "menu-overlay" only when the `.offcanvas-collapse` hasClass `.open`. I have a function to toggle the open class to `.offcanvas-collapse` so I know I can't write a function based around a toggle class

```
$('[data-toggle="offcanvas"]').on('click', function () {
        $('.offcanvas-collapse').toggleClass('open');
    });

    $('.offcanvas-collapse.open').each(function () {
        $(".menu-overlay").toggleClass("d-none");
    });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example It is also advisable to take the Tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050761/toggle-visibility-property-of-div

Comment: @LeeLieser did any of these answers help? If so, please be sure to mark the answer as accepted so others can find the solution if they are having similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `hasClass()` functionality.

```
$('[data-toggle="offcanvas"]').on('click', function () {
  if ($('[data-toggle="offcanvas"]').hasClass('open')) {
     $('.offcanvas-collapse').toggleClass('close');
  } else {
     $('.offcanvas-collapse').toggleClass('open');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('[data-toggle="offcanvas"]').on('click', function () {
  if($(this).hasClass('open')) {
    $(".menu-overlay").removeClass("d-none");
    $(this).removeClass('open');
  }
  else {
    $(this).addClass('open');
    $(".menu-overlay").addClass("d-none");
  }
});
```

Comment: it looks like you can't target a already toggleClass with the hasClass functionality